# Can anyone explain this session storage code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, session-storage

I've been going through someone else's code and fixing things up a little bit and I've run into some code I don't quite understand. Could you explain to me what's going on here and the implications of how it's implemented and maybe better solution to handle the session storage for the use case or just a better way to write the code?

```
//Load Content from Cache if this is not a Refresh or new Page Load
        if ((document.referrer!=null)&&(sessionStorage.getItem('lastReferrer')!=document.referrer)){
          if (('sessionStorage' in window) && (window['sessionStorage'] !== null)) {
            if ('@Name'+window.location.href in sessionStorage){
              $("#@Name").html(sessionStorage.getItem('@Name'+window.location.href));
              $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.getItem('@Name'+'ScrollPos'+window.location.href));
              jQuery.data($('#ResponderScripts')[0],'cs_page',sessionStorage.getItem('@Name'+'Page'+window.location.href));
              jQuery.data($('#ResponderScripts')[0],'cs_totalPages',sessionStorage.getItem('@Name'+'TotalPage'+window.location.href));
              pageLoadedFromCache=1;
              console.log('Replaced from Cache: @name url='+window.location.href+'  referrer='+document.referrer+' page='+$('#ResponderScripts').data("cs_page"));
            }
          }
        };

        // Save Component Content when leaving the page.
        $(window).unload(function() {
          history.replaceState({}, document.title,window.location.href);
          if (('sessionStorage' in window) && (window['sessionStorage'] !== null)) {
            var componentContent = $("#@Name").html();
            if (componentContent!=null){
              sessionStorage.setItem('@Name'+window.location.href, componentContent);
              sessionStorage.setItem('@Name'+'ScrollPos'+window.location.href,$(window).scrollTop());
              sessionStorage.setItem('@Name'+'Page'+window.location.href,$('#ResponderScripts').data("cs_page"));
              sessionStorage.setItem('@Name'+'TotalPage'+window.location.href,$('#ResponderScripts').data("cs_totalPages"));
              console.log('stored @name url='+window.location.href+' referrer='+document.referrer+' page='+sessionStorage.getItem('@Name'+'Page'+window.location.href));
            }
          }
        });
```

Thanks any help is appreciated!
If this isn't the place for this let me know and I can remove it.

Comment: Instead of downvoting me could you just tell me if this isn't the place for this, losing rep hurts when I have so little.

Comment: It looks like it does what it says, loading content from cache if it's not a refresh or new page load. Honestly, I don't know how he would do that (unless it's really huge pages on a slow network).

Comment: This is written to handle infinite scroll and ajax browser history stuff. Would I be better of rewriting it completely or is this up to standard?

Answer (score 3):

This snippet seems pretty clear and thought out to me, but I'll decompose what's going on.

```
if ((document.referrer != null) && (sessionStorage.getItem('lastReferrer') != document.referrer))
```

So here we determine if the session is continuous. The statement evaluates true if the referrer and the last known session referrer are different.

```
if (('sessionStorage' in window) && (window['sessionStorage'] !== null))
```

Here we determine whether sessionStorage is even a thing in the browser, and whether it's been set. Returns true if it's available and set. I'd move this outside the referral check for safety concerns (Possible null or undefined access).

```
if ('@Name'+window.location.href in sessionStorage)
```

Now we determine whether the page itself has a property in the sessionStorage. If it is, then load the content stored in sessionStorage rather than load the page.

The next section is even easier. It registers a *callback function* to be called when the page is being unloaded (navigation, browser close, etc.) This function performs `history.replaceState()` and determines if sessionStorage is available (Again). If it is, it saves a bunch of state info to reload next time the page is accessed.

The only thing I'd do is wrap both the save and load logic in the sessionStorage check. If sessionStorage isn't available, why waste time on the other conditionals at all? Do note that this is in context of the snippet, and may not work out for you in the full app's context.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation. Just out of curiosity what does null or undefined access mean and what are the safety implications?

Comment: A property that has a value of null is considered to exist while having no value (The null definition in a nutshell). A property that is undefined has no value, no type, nothing. To speak in JS: `var a; console.log(typeof(a));` logs a type of 'undefined' whereas `var a; a = null; console.log(typeof(a));` logs a type of 'Object'.

Comment: To make it clear why I see this null check as both a null and undefined issue: `!=` allows coercion, meaning undefined can be equated to null. Any further changes I'd make would start with replacing `!=` and `==` (Equality) with `!==` and `===` (Identity) then dealing with the torrent of errors that getting rid of coercion in favor of identity checks likely causes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

This code looks to be preserving a page (paginated list?) in local store so that it can be reconstituted from cache.  I have rewritten it in a way that I hope adds clarity.

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;

// **************************************
// Set some keys that can be used to access the localstore cache
// **************************************
var lastHTMLContent_key = '@Name' + currentUrl;
var lastScrollPosition_key = '@Name' + 'ScrollPos' + currentUrl;
var lastPage_key = '@Name' + 'Page' + currentUrl;
var lastPageTotal_key = '@Name' + 'TotalPage' + currentUrl;
// **************************************

var $ResponderScripts = $('#ResponderScripts');
var $Target = $("#@Name");

// **************************************
// Some tests to determine if we can successfully retrieve an item from the cache
// Note: Moved here for clarity.  It is actually important to do these tests in a
// way that prevents null references.
// **************************************
var isSessionStorageAvailable = ('sessionStorage' in window && window['sessionStorage'] !== null);
var isNewReferrer = (document.referrer != null && document.referrer != sessionStorage.getItem('lastReferrer');
var isURLInStore = ( lastHTMLContent_key in sessionStorage );
// **************************************

// **************************************
// Load Content from Cache if this is not a Refresh or new Page Load
// **************************************
if (isSessionStorageAvailable && isNewReferrer && isURLInStore) {

    pageLoadedFromCache = 1;

    // **************************************
    // Fetch prior cached content
    // **************************************
    var lastHTMLContent = sessionStorage.getItem(lastHTMLContent_key);
    var lastScrollPosition = sessionStorage.getItem(lastScrollPosition_key);
    var lastPage = sessionStorage.getItem(lastPage_key);
    var lastPageTotal = sessionStorage.getItem(lastPageTotal_key);
    // **************************************

    // **************************************
    // Set current content/context based on prior
    // **************************************
    $Target.html(lastHTMLContent);
    $(window).scrollTop(lastScrollPosition);
    jQuery.data($ResponderScripts[0], 'cs_page', lastPage);
    jQuery.data($ResponderScripts[0], 'cs_totalPages', lastPageTotal);
    // **************************************

    console.log('Replaced from Cache: @name url=' + currentUrl + '  referrer=' + document.referrer + ' page=' + $('#ResponderScripts').data("cs_page"));
}
// **************************************

// **************************************
// Save Component Content when leaving the page.
// **************************************
$(window).unload(function() {

    history.replaceState({}, document.title, currentUrl);

    if (isSessionStorageAvailable) {
        var targetHTML = $Target.html();
        if (targetHTML != null){

            // **************************************
            // Save existing content for next time...
            // **************************************
            sessionStorage.setItem(lastHTMLContent_key, targetHTML);
            sessionStorage.setItem(lastScrollPosition_key, $(window).scrollTop());
            sessionStorage.setItem(lastPage_key, $ResponderScripts.data("cs_page"));
            sessionStorage.setItem(lastPageTotal_key, $ResponderScripts.data("cs_totalPages"));
            // **************************************

            console.log('stored @name url=' + currentUrl + ' referrer=' + document.referrer + ' page=' + $('#ResponderScripts').data("cs_page"));

        }
    }

});
// **************************************
```

I think this is how I might approach the more complicated **if**:

```
if (
    window.sessionStorage &&  // we can work with sessionStorage
    sessionStorage[lastHTMLContent_key] && // a value for this page is in the store
    document.referrer &&  // there is a referrer
    document.referrer != sessionStorage.getItem('lastReferrer') // the referrer is not the last referrer
) {
    // proper to use cache page data
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful! Two quick questions what is the safety risk with null references? And would you say this method is up to standards will this not overload the session storage is there a better method to handle this?

Comment: As far as "up to standards", I would say at the moment no.  The current example places a bunch of stuff in the global context and that is not great.  It would not be too difficult to wrap it in a closure and that would be a good start.  Let me know if you would like to see that.  I'll edit the example with how I would think about writing that more complicated if statement now

Comment: I would love to see your implementation. Sadly the whole session storage is beyond me especially with standards and how to handle it. Could this method overload the session storage is it bad practice to store too much there, should we only store the past two instances? Sorry for all the questions.